# Making a C++ easily importable into IDEs

Tags: c++, ide

Currently I'm working on an open source C++ project on my Linux machine using VIM and Makefiles.
The project files are organized into separate directories, the most important ones being `include` for header files and `src` for source files.

The source code and the project dependencies are already multiplatform so I don't have to worry about that. However I would like to make my project easily importable into the most popular IDEs such as Microsoft Visual Studio and Code::Blocks. How should I go about that?

Comment: create project files for each IDE and add them into your project's source tree?

Comment: Well, if it's really that easy then sorry for the dumb question. Thanks to my habbit of using VIM for everything I don't really know how project management works in IDEs. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend something like [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) to generate the Makefiles for you.  Most IDEs have support for it out of the box or with a plugin.